# iOS Use third party SDK Apple Match-O linker error

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an app that requires sipphone .

**AppDelegate.m** add

```
portSIPSDK = [[PortSIPSDK alloc] init]
```

I will get 142 errors

> Apple Mach-O Linker Error.

Here are the errors i get:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do we have to use cocoapods??

Comment: Did you set additional linked flag "-ObjC" ?

Comment: I try to add other linked flag "-ObjC" . it still same error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project go to Build Settings -> Search Paths. For the option **Framework Search Paths** remove any search paths that are different from your application folder path.

Then relink your frameworks into the project. Be sure to copy the items into the application directory. (Click the checkmark while adding the framework to your project).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Have you moved your project to another folder? I see a warning in the screenshot saying directory not found F:/users/sonas/Desktop/jackFile/SurveillApp

Comment: I remove framework path , I post remain the errors picture other answer .

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Build Settings -> architectures section?
I think your problem is with architectures, 

if  $(ARCHS_STANDARD) is not the default architecture of your application please set it so

Comment: OK, Build Settings -> architectures section . Picture URL : http://imgur.com/ewT0jbm

Comment: I find question less libstdc.dylib  and libc++.dylib , very thank for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve framework path question problem

Here are the errors :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L96py.jpg